# Adding values to DataFrame from CSV file based on key identifier?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently merging three different data-sets, where all three sets contain a special identifier which in one of the sets can appear multiple times.

Now I created a dataFrame from my main .csv file, and want to add values to this data frame iff the identifier is the exact same in the other .csv files.

In advance,
Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use merge:

```
df = df.merge(df_2, how='left', on='id_name')
```

where `on='id_name'` your identifier.

Your can read more here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: How can you possibly answer the question? You're just repeating the documentation.

Comment: @roganjosh question - how merging dataframes. This is simple question, and simple answer.

Comment: Then dupe it. The OP didn't even ask a question.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear - or even missing - actually @RudolfMorkovskyi's answer is exactly what I was missing. PS: Very new to pandas. Thank you.